# PostgreSQL 9.6 Database Server is Down do I need to start Wildfly 8.1 server

Tags: postgresql, wildfly, postgresql-9.6

PostgreSQL 9.6 Database Server went Down, Widfly is using  connection pooling to the Postgresql 9.6 Server.
So  what should be the sequence.
1. Should I start Postgresql 9.6 Server and everything should work fine ?
Or
1. Start Postgresql 9.6 Server
2. Restart Wildfly Instance to that it can pick up connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both JBoss AS 7.x and wildfly  if you want the connection pool to recover from a database outage then we need to configure connection validation. Go through [document](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch13s13.html) for more details on `<validate-on-match>, <background-validation>, <background-validation-millis>, <valid-connection-checker-class-name>, and <check-valid-connection-sql>`.